# Laravel redirect to root url instead previous when validating failed

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a crucial issue with my Laravel application. When a validation failed, Laravel redirects request to root URL instead previous. I try with using FormRequest but still giving the same result.

Then I checked the previous URL (using `url()->previous()` methods) with different routes, every time it returned root URL...

Here is the session config file. (as I know Laravel gets the previous URL from the session)

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 300),
'expire_on_close' => false,
'encrypt' => false,
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'connection' => null,
'table' => 'sessions',
'store' => null,
'lottery' => [2, 100],
'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
),
'path' => '/',
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'http_only' => true,
'same_site' => null,
```

I'm using redis as session driver, I already using redis as cache driver and it works fine.

I'm digging changes that I made but still couldn't figure out what caused kind of error..

## !!!

I solved my issue and meta referrer tag was causing that issue.

`<meta name="referrer" content="origin">` I removed that line and it returned to normal. But I don't think that it's good approach I go with     `origin-when-cross-origin` option

Comment: which validation are you talking about?

Comment: Well, first of all, it is not an error, and second, maybe you have a redirect somewhere in between which flushes the previous URL from the session.

Comment: If you are using the form then it will automatically re directly to your form.

Comment: @BILALMALIK form validation

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facades Validator-

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

```
    $change= [
        'code.required' => 'Code is required',
        'xyz.required' => 'Please enter xyz'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'code' => 'required',
        'api_token' => 'required',
    ], $change);

    // if validation fails 
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        //redirect here
    } else {
        //code
    }
```

Does this help?

Comment: problem happens while redirect. Previous url point to root url not actual previous url

Comment: I don't understand  what you mean by "previous url" .. why it should go to previous url, if it fails then it should be on the same url, isn't it, if you redirect on different page when it fails, why should it not get redirected ?... looking at you stackoverflow stats i believe you must have seen your .htaccess. ... sorry if I confused you more because I myself is confused at your question

Comment: by previous url I meant http referrer url. Also how it could be in the same url ? One url for display html and another for store inputs. @BILALMALIK

Comment: also the problem is, why the real problem is referrer seems as root url. I couldn't find the reason behind this

Comment: I think we will be talking very abstract without the code.... are we talking anything after redirect() function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Validator

use Validator;

```
$validatior = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'form_field_name1' => 'required',
    'form_field_name2' => 'required',
]);

if ($validatior->fails())
{
    // return to previous url
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validatior);
} else {
    // Do code here
}
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to change the apache headers from:

```
Header set Referrer-Policy: strict-origin
```

to:

```
Header set Referrer-Policy: same-origin
```